# Squid whitelist only for one auth user

Tags: proxy, squid

To be honest, I'm not sure if this is easy to do (or possible for that matter) as I've combed over the squid docs and didn't find what I needed.

I am using a squid4 proxy with basic ncsa authentication. Here's what I would like to accomplish, I have two users on my proxy with ncsa authentication. I would like for one user to be able to access anything on the proxy (standard `http_access allow`), and the other user to be limited to a whitelist of one url that they can access.

Here is the authentication portion of my `squid.conf`:

```
auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid/basic_ncsa_auth /etc/squid/passwd
acl squid_users proxy_auth REQUIRED
http_access deny !squid_users
http_access allow squid_users
http_access deny all
```

Is there a way to `http_access allow/deny` for only one user with authentication, or am I missing something?

I don't really know what to do for this one factor so any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can't expect to have squid treat the users differently if you don't separate them in your config.

take a look at the "a more complex example" at: https://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Authenticate/Bypass

specifically, after defining the `auth_param` section, you should use something like:

```
acl UsersGroupA proxy_auth "/etc/squid/groupa.txt"
acl SitesGroupA dstdomain "/etc/squid/sites.a.txt"
acl UsersGroupB proxy_auth "/etc/squid/groupb.txt"
acl authenticated_users proxy_auth REQUIRED

# rules allowing authenticated users
http_access allow SitesGroupA UsersGroupA     # this will force both whitelisted urls AND users of group "A" (the limited group)
http_access allow UsersGroupB                 # this will only force users of group B (the unlimited group)

# catch-all rule
http_access deny all
```

and additionally, if you need to specify ports, you should do that on the same line:

```
acl port_80 port 80
acl port_443 port 443
http_access allow http port_80 SitesGroupA UsersGroupA
http_access allow CONNECT port_443 SitesGroupA UsersGroupA
```